# How to track wordpress sub folders html page in google ananlytics

Tags: previews, google-analytics

in wordpress site i created one one folder & put some html files(www.mywebsite.com/global/page.html).

But google analytics is not tracking those html pages(www.mywebsite.com/global/page.html).

Is there any solution to track those pages likewise the wordpress pages.

Your feedback will be highly appreciated.

THANKS.

Comment: Does the page have your GA code in it? If not, the page won't be tracked.

Answer (score 1):

If the HTML files are outside of your wordpress installation, you need to insert the Google Analytics tracking code into each of the HTML pages manually. 
For the Wordpress pages, you can insert the code into your Theme's header file (usually header.php) or similar or use one of the many plugins to do this.

Comment: its mean i have to create google analytics property for www.mywebsite.com/global directory & put the code in each page

Comment: You can use the same tracking code as Google Analytics will tell you what pages were viewed so you don't need to have a different property.